# Railities using incorrect Rake version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting the following error when running my Rails 3.2.9 application

```
Could not find rake-10.0.3 in any of the sources
```

I believe that it is caused by the fact that rake is calling for version 10.0.3 and railities is specifying > 0.8.7 in my gemlock file.

```
railties (3.2.9)
  actionpack (= 3.2.9)
  activesupport (= 3.2.9)
  rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  rdoc (~> 3.4)
  thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
rake (10.0.3)
```

Is there a way to specify the version dependency of railities?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

fixed the issue.